# Mockito UnfinishedStubbingException

Tags: java, mockito

I am new to Mockito, I have tried looking into this Exception but I haven´t found a concrete answer. It happens in my code when I use two mocks together, meaning that I give through the constructor of a mock, another mock. Like so:

```
...
OperationNode child = getNode(Operation.ADD);
child.insertNode(getConstantNode(getIntegerValue(2));
...

 private ConstantNode getConstantNode(NumericalValue value){
    ConstantNode node = Mockito.mock(ConstantNode.class);
    Mockito.when(node.evaluate()).thenReturn(value);
    Mockito.when(node.toString()).thenReturn(value.toString());
    return node;
}

private IntegerValue getIntegerValue(int number) {
   IntegerValue integerValue = Mockito.mock(IntegerValue.class);
   Mockito.when(integerValue.getValue()).thenReturn(number);
   Mockito.when(integerValue.toString()).thenReturn(Integer.toString(number));
   return integerValue;
}
```

In one of the forums I read about not sending a mock through a constructor of another mock, since Mockito might get confused with the mock calls, so I tried the following:

```
NumericalValue value = getIntegerValue(2);
child.insertNode(getConstantNode(value));
```

But to no avail. I make sure that only the methods `toString()` and `getValue()` are called, because those are the only methods the class has. I don´t understand what´s going on.

I have also tried using the mocks separately, to see if I have done something wrong:

```
child.insertNode(new ConstantNode(getIntegerValue(2)));
```

That works perfectly.

```
child.insertNode(getConstantNode(new IntegerValue(2)));
```

That works fine too.

Comment: known issue `https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=53`

Comment: Clickable link: https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=53

Comment: Mocks returning mocks is usually a code smell.

Comment: As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77569633/3679900) I was getting this exception with `PowerMockito`'s `mockStatic` since I had forgotten to add `@PrepareForTest({ClassToMock.class})` annotation on my test-class

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From what I read on "Issue 53" of mockito (https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=53) , my code was experiencing a problem due to the validation framework involved in Mockito. Precisely the following code was causing the exception per se.

```
private ConstantNode getConstantNode(NumericalValue value){
    ConstantNode node = Mockito.mock(ConstantNode.class);
    Mockito.when(node.evaluate()).thenReturn(value);
    Mockito.when(node.toString()).thenReturn(value.toString());
    return node;
}
```

If you remember from my code, the parameter value is ALSO A MOCK, so that when `value.toString()` is called on the `thenReturn()`, I believe (and someone please correct me if I am wrong) that the validation framework is triggered and makes sure that every "when" has had its `thenReturn()` called/validated/etc. So that if this happenes, the  `Mockito.when(node.toString()).thenReturn(value.toString()` **will not be validated** because it hasn´t returned from the `valute.toString()`, which started the whole "validate everything" chain.

How I fixed it:

```
private ConstantNode getConstantNode(NumericalValue value){
    ConstantNode node = Mockito.mock(ConstantNode.class);
    Mockito.when(node.evaluate()).thenReturn(value);

    String numberToString = value.toString();

    Mockito.when(node.toString()).thenReturn(numberToString);
    return node;
}
```

This way, it **can** be validated. I find this a complete code smell because I will literally have to leave a comment that explains why I am using a seemingly useless intermediate variable in the code.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks! Finally I'm starting to understand this weird problem.

Answer (score 11):

There are some good fixes posted in this question already, but for anyone still having trouble understanding it, think of the order in which Java calls all those methods. According to the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html), Java [evaluates every parameter of a method left-to-right before calling the method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7):

1. `integerValue.getValue()`, which Mockito records
2. `when`, where Mockito takes the last call (to `integer.getValue`) and starts setting up stubbing
3. `value.toString`, which is a mocked call that Mockito records
4. `thenReturn` on the stubber

Mockito complains exactly because the call to the mock, step 3, happens *after* step 2 (`when`) but *before* step 4 (`thenReturn`), causing the validation framework to complain about the stubbing. Joy, your answer moves the troublesome step 3 to before step 1, which is fine; Sajan removes it from the statement entirely, which is also fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with line

`Mockito.when(node.toString()).thenReturn(value.toString());` in method `getConstantNode`

Try removing the line and check if it works.
May be you can do something like

```
int num = 2;
child.insertNode(getConstantNode(getIntegerValue(num), num);
...

 private ConstantNode getConstantNode(NumericalValue value){
    ConstantNode node = Mockito.mock(ConstantNode.class);
    Mockito.when(node.evaluate()).thenReturn(value);
    Mockito.when(node.toString()).thenReturn(Integer.toString(number));
    return node;
}

private IntegerValue getIntegerValue(int number) {
   IntegerValue integerValue = Mockito.mock(IntegerValue.class);
   Mockito.when(integerValue.getValue()).thenReturn(number);
   return integerValue;
}
```

Comment: Where is "number" coming from then?

Comment: It solved the exception problem, but I still don´t understand the dynamics as to why it´s happening. I read the issue link placed in the first comment, but I still don´t understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with the ordering of the calls and Mockito Framework validation.  Try this and see if it helps:

```
...
OperationNode child = getNode(Operation.ADD);
IntegerValue value = getIntegerValue(2);
ConstantNode node =  Mockito.mock(ConstantNode.class);
Mockito.when(node.evaluate()).thenReturn(value);
Mockito.when(node.toString()).thenReturn(value.toString());
child.insertNode(node);

...

private IntegerValue getIntegerValue(int number) {
   IntegerValue integerValue = Mockito.mock(IntegerValue.class);
   Mockito.when(integerValue.getValue()).thenReturn(number);
   Mockito.when(integerValue.toString()).thenReturn(Integer.toString(number));
   return integerValue;
}
```

Source: https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=53

Comment: Isn´t that the same thing, just without a method in the way? ... Eitherway, I tried it, no use.

Answer (score 0):

One further possible cause of this problem which had me scratching my head for AGES. I was mocking multiple method calls and one of them was missing a `thenReturn` but the stack trace produced by mockito referenced the first mocked call (which did have a `thenReturn`) rather than the one that had the actual problem, so it took me a long time to spot it. This is really confusing behaviour!

```
Mockito.when(service.method1()).thenReturn(value1); // stacktrace pointed here
Mockito.when(service.method2()).thenReturn(value2);
Mockito.when(service.method3()); // missing thenReturn()
```