# Unfinished stubbing Exception when using PowerMockito & Mockito

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to use PowerMockito & Mockito as shown below:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({AmqpMessagePublisher.class})
public class OrderItemManagerImplTest {

 @Spy
 @InjectMocks
 private OrderItemManager orderItemManager = new OrderItemManagerImpl();

 @Mock
 private OrderReleaseManager srReleaseManager;

 @Spy
 private srOrderTransformer srOrderTransformer;

 private OrderItemEntry getOrderItemEntry() {
  OrderItemEntry orderItemEntry = new OrderItemEntry();
  orderItemEntry.setProcessingStartDate("2017-03-01");
  return orderItemEntry;
 }

 @Before
 public void setUp() throws Exception {
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  PowerMockito.mockStatic(AmqpMessagePublisher.class);
  PowerMockito.doNothing().when(AmqpMessagePublisher.class);
 }

 @Test
 public void testCreateOrder() throws Exception {
  OrderItemEntry expected = getOrderItemEntry();
  String expectedItemId = expected.getItems().get(0).getItemId(); 
  // the below line is throwing the exception      
  Mockito.when(srReleaseManager.getReleaseByStoreReleaseId(expectedItemId)).thenReturn(null); 
 }
}
```

On trying to test the above code it is throwing the exception

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.PowerMockitoCore.doAnswer(PowerMockitoCore.java:36)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed

    at com.myntra.sr.manager.impl.jb.OrderItemManagerImplTest.testCreateOrder(OrderItemManagerImplTest.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390146/mockito-unfinishedstubbingexception-with-when-thenreturn) question and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318569/unfinished-stubbing-detected-in-mockito) question. But none of them helped. Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to call the static method after mocking it.  See example below.

```
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(StaticService.class);
StaticService.executeMethod();
```

reference: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#how-to-stub-void-static-method-to-throw-exception

EDIT:

> So should I move PowerMockito.doNothing().when(AmqpMessagePublisher.class); inside testCreateOrder from testSetup and call the method from which AmqpMessagePublisher is getting called?

You can leave it where it is.  The problem is this.  When you are mocking a void static method things get a little tricky in PowerMocks API.  The traditional `doNothing().when(someObject).mockedMethod();` does not work.  The way they went about solving this is a little weird.  They want you to call the actual static void method being mocked, right after the `doNothing().when(AmqpMessagePublisher.class)` line.  This tells PowerMock which static method to mock from AmqpMessagePublisher.  So for example lets say you had 10 static void methods in AmqpMessagePublisher, the `doNothing()` does not convey which of them to mock.  But the next immediate line does.

Comment: That is what I am doing right. In `setUp()` I have called `PowerMockito.mockStatic(AmqpMessagePublisher.class)`.

Comment: yeah, after that call the method.

Comment: The method is getting called in `testCreateOrder`. In `setUp` I have called `mockStatic`. So anyways I am already doing what you are suggesting.

Comment: You don't understand, you have to cal the method you want to mock right after the doNothing line.  In your code you are not doing what the article and I am suggesting.

Comment: I have gone through the link. So should I move `PowerMockito.doNothing().when(AmqpMessagePublisher.class);` inside `testCreateOrder` from `testSetup` and call the method from which `AmqpMessagePublisher` is getting called?

Comment: Yes it helps. Thanks. True a little weird.