# How to fix UnfinishedStubbingException

Tags: java, mockito, integration-testing

```
@MockBean
private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

@MockBean
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@InjectMocks
private FetchCoreVersionsList fetchCoreVersionsList;

 @Test
public void testCoreVersionsJsonHandle() throws Exception{
    when(restTemplate.getForObject("https://openmrs.jfrog.io/openmrs/api/storage/public/org/openmrs/api/openmrs-api/",
            String.class))
            .thenReturn(new ObjectMapper().readValue(getFileAsString("core-versions.json"), String.class));

}
```

On running the test , I get the following error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException:
```

Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at org.openmrs.addonindex.scheduled.FetchCoreVersionsListIT.testCoreVersionsJsonHandle(FetchCoreVersionsListIT.java:66)

I am pretty new to creating test cases so kindly bear with me if its something silly :)

Comment: What is the expected return type of `getForObject()` and what does `readValue()` return? And did you do some research - I see many questions for that exception ... like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554119/mockito-unfinishedstubbingexception

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with Spring Boot 2.0:

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootTest @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class myTests() {

    @MockBean RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        String uri = "http://example.org", msg="hello";
        Mockito.doReturn(msg).when(restTemplate).getForObject(eq(uri),any());
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(uri,String.class);
        Mockito.verify(restTemplate).getForObject(eq(uri),any());
        assertEquals(response,msg);
    }

}
```

---

Mockito offers two different syntaxes:
[Mockito - difference between doReturn() and when()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20353846/86967)

```
Mockito.doReturn(new ResponseEntity<String>("200 OK",HttpStatus.OK)).when(restTemplate).postForEntity(eq(url),any(),eq(String.class));
// or
Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(eq(url), any(), eq(String.class))).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<String>("200 OK", HttpStatus.OK));
```

There are other tricks, such as using `eq(String.class)` instead of just `String.class`.  The error output attempts to walk you through this to degree.

Comment: I had some problems using `any()` for the URI string -- don't know why.

Comment: ...I had better luck with `anyString()`.