# Mockito when method working only on debug

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, tdd, spock

I have an issue while mocking one of interface values. When I am running test in debug mode it is working fine but while run I have `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException`.

Update 16.08.2018: it's working only when I set up breakpoint on broken line or before -  without it test crashes also on debug. And if I hold F9 all the time some test passes and some fail so it have to be connected with time of inicialization but still no idea how to fix it

On debug mode it passes but on run mode I got exception in Service while executing: `String name = getPhoneBookName();`

I also try to move `Mockito.when` to setup block but it doesn't help

Any ideas?

Code looks like:

MyServiceSpec:

```
private PropertyDAO propertyDAO = mock(PropertyDAO.class)     

def "Should fill all fields property for existing user"() {

given:"mock values to check proper form" 
when(propertyDAO.getValue(PropertyDAO.Key.REMOTE_BOOK_NAME)).thenReturn("Phonebook")

when: 
service.someMethod()
```

Service:

```
someMethod() {
    String name = getPhoneBookName();
    if (name != null) {
        map.put("remotePhoneBookName", name);
    }
}

@Override
public String getPhoneBookName() {
    return propertyDAO.getValue(PropertyDAO.Key.REMOTE_BOOK_NAME);
}
```

PropertyDao

```
public interface PropertyDAO {
String VERSION_KEY = "VERSION";

public enum Key {
    VERSION,
    REMOTE_BOOK_NAME
}
String getValue(Key key);
```

PropertyHibernateDAO

```
@Repository("propertyDAO")
@Qualifier("hibernate")
public class PropertyHibernateDAO implements PropertyDAO {

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public String getValue(Key key) {
    String result = null;
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    String dbKey = DB_KEYS.get(key);
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Property.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("key", dbKey));
    Property property = (Property) criteria.uniqueResult();
    if (property != null) {
        result = property.getValue();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Is it related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554119/mockito-unfinishedstubbingexception ?

Comment: I don't think so because in my case I try to return simple text not any variable. But I make one more discovery: main problem is mock of propertyDao. In my class that is autowired by service (ConfigurationImpl.class) I got one more place that use it: 
 switch (propertyDAO.getAcsConfig().getLang()) { 
someLogic
}
And it also crash here on run not on debug :/ 
I think that it can be caused of inicialization of that class 
configurationImpl.init(propertyDAO, mock(PhoneModelDAO.class))

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got it.

It turns out that in my test below critical mock I try to mock someMethod() from the question and then it crash on execution. Thank You very much @Michał Piątkowski because at the end You was right ;)

It works when I replace :

```
     when(propertyDAO.getValue(PropertyDAO.Key.REMOTE_BOOK_NAME)).thenReturn("Phonebook")
 when(configuration.getStationValues(any(), any(), anyString())).thenReturn(someMethod())
```

to

```
     when(propertyDAO.getValue(PropertyDAO.Key.REMOTE_BOOK_NAME)).thenReturn("Phonebook") 
def method =someMethod() 
when(configuration.getStationValues(any(), any(), anyString())).thenReturn(method)
```

You can feel code smell even in next building, but I do not have idea about another workaround for now