# Mockito doNothing UnfinishedStubbingException

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I am trying to spy/mock and return a dummy Url when `spyAnotherService.getUrl(ID)` within another method which is `myService.deleteSomething(name, spyAnotherService.getRepApiServiceUrl(ID))` this method has a void return type. But it complains that `UnfinishedStubbingException`. I checked the examples on the web but none of them matches what I am trying to here

```java
MyService myService = Mockito.mock(MyService.class);
AnotherService spyAnotherService = Mockito.spy(AnotherService.class);
Mockito.when(spyAnotherService.getUrl(ID)).thenReturn(URL);
Mockito.doNothing().when(myService).deleteSomething(name, spyAnotherService.getRepApiServiceUrl(ID));
```

Comment: This may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15560154/259889

Answer (score 0):

You can spy the class

```
MyService myService = Mockito.spy(MyService.class);
```

But you [don't need](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-void-methods) to do nothing (also literally)

> However, doNothing() is Mockito's default behavior for void methods.